# Liferay 7.2 Edit Blog Entry Html

Tags: liferay, blogs

I have Lifeary 7.2

I found the way to edit the template of List of Blogs Entries but i don't find the way to edit the html or template of a single entry.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the single entity post html, because the template rules this for all posts.

Instead you can edit the specific blog content post, as html.

Comment: I think to override the jsp file because i have a better control to all DOM.

Comment: Wrong way! Liferay it's a powerful CMS, not a jhispter project

Comment: I will do it with a fragment module. Filters doesn't let me to edit html but a string. If you think that is a wrong way, wich is the right way